# Cannot construct a WebException

Tags: c#, webclient, system.net

I have a method where I call DownloadData on a WebClient. This method throws an exception since the URL returns 404. This is all expected by specifications since the resource does not exist.

Web client will throw a WebException and I have to read body from respose since it contains JSON object with detailed error. After that I have to throw a WebException again since the layer up still expects the WebException. At the moment I am trying to construct a WebException with details from the current one as follows:

```
catch(WebException ex)
{
   var response = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();   
   dynamic error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
   throw new WebException(error.message, null, ex.Status, ex.Response);
}
```

The problem is I get an exception while constructing WebException. This is the message!

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Net.WebException.WebException(string,
>   System.Net.WebExceptionStatus, System.Net.WebExceptionInternalStatus,
>   System.Exception)' has some invalid arguments

It is like this constructor does not exist! Check the constructor in exception and check the constructor in catch block.

As you can see I am using a valid constructor. Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2zywh13(v=vs.110).aspx).

What is happening here?

Comment: Read the error, your parameters that you are passing through are incorrect

Comment: Try casting your `null` - sounds weird, I know, but this can help with overload resolution (if that is really the problem).

Comment: Also try using `string message = error.message;` and then using that - so that the overload resolution will occur at compile-time instead of at execution time.

Comment: I would avoid using dymanic in this case. Just do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response)` instead, then you do `error['message'].ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you need to cast `error.message` as string. It would be even better if you would handle that string differently so you can verify if that `error.message` exists.

```
catch(WebException ex)
{
    var response = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();   
    dynamic error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
    throw new WebException((string)error.message, null, ex.Status, ex.Response);
}
```

Comment: As I said, try putting addtional check for error object, becaus it may not contain message property and then you will have another exception :)